# Qwt: How to delete all items(curves, markers, etc...) from plot

Tags: qt, qwt

I want to delete all items from my plot. I found this:

```
plot->detachItems( QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotCurve ,true);
plot->detachItems( QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotMarker,true);
```

But, it does not delete clearly. Somethings remains background. I tried on a example. And memory leaks occurs. How can clear all plot?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `QwtPlot::replot()` after modifying your plot. Add this line after your code:

```
plot->replot();
```

Or you can enable auto replot during initialization, `QwtPlot::setAutoReplot(true)`, that way you don't have to call replot every time you change something. On the other hand, if you frequently update your plot, I would advise agains auto replot due to performance reasons. It's better to call `replot()` explicitly in such case.